# How to extract json object from string which contains curly brackets in value by Regex

Tags: java, json, regex

In my case, I want to extract every JSON object in the string by regular expression.

For exp:

The string is: The value of

```
{"Name":"Jenkins url (Build Information)","Type":null,"Id":null,"Value":null} and {"Name":"}Tomcat{"}
```

by 200/KUS/AUTOMIC.

JSON objects will be extracted:

```
{"Name":"Jenkins url (Build Information)","Type":null,"Id":null,"Value":null}
```

And

```
{"Name":"}Tomcat{"}
```

*Note:
I tried the regex its

```
"\\{(?:[^}{]+|\\{(?:[^}{]+|\\{[^)(]*\\})*\\})*\\}"
```

But it can extract

```
{"Name":"Jenkins url (Build Information)","Type":null,"Id":null,"Value":null} and **{"Name":"}
```

So that the last JSON object is not valid. Does anyone have any idea?

Many thanks

Comment: The original string doesn't seem to contain valid JSON objectS?

Comment: @Evan The valid JSON objects are {"Name":"Jenkins url (Build Information)","Type":null,"Id":null,"Value":null} and {"Name":"}Tomcat{"}. But I cannot get the last one from the string by using that regex :(

Comment: Ah, I see. https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/3987/is-json-a-regular-language

Comment: :( Do you have any better another idea to solve my problem?

Comment: @anhnv I checked your regex and it picks all 3 JSON documents regardless of the validity. Check the simulation here. http://regexr.com/3gpo3

Answer (score 0):

I checked your regex and it picks all 3 JSON documents regardless of the validity. Check the simulation [here](https://regexr.com/3gpo3).

Comment: It's not correct because I just pick 2 JSON objects and the last one has value like }Tomcat{